# Duplicate local variable mp2

Tags: imagebutton

I'm trying on my own at Android Programming. Trying to write a program consisting of 3 Image Buttons, if first one clicked, music plays, with a certain message display and if the second pressed, another music will play along with another message display. But the error message says "Duplicate local variable mp2" at the second line of the coding written for the second medialplayer. Kindly guide me.

```
package com.example.imagebutton;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        try{


            final MediaPlayer mp1;
            final MediaPlayer mp2 = null;


       ImageButton ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
       mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzikone);

        ib1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {

            private MediaPlayer mp3;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Button Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(mp2.isPlaying()){
                    mp2.reset();
                }else{
                    mp3.reset();
                }
                 mp1.start();


            }    



        });


        ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muziktwo);

         ib2.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Second Button Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(mp1.isPlaying()){
                    mp1.reset();
                }

                 mp2.start();


            }    



        });




         ImageButton ib3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
         final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzikthree);

          ib3.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Third Button Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(mp1.isPlaying()){
                    mp1.reset();
                }else{
                    mp2.reset();
                }

                 mp3.start();


            }    



        });


    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mp2` is declared twice as stated by the message, here:

```
final MediaPlayer mp2 = null;
```

and here

```
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muziktwo);
```

To fix the issue, remove one of the declarations.

NB: I think you have some serious scope issue in your code, reading [this lesson](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/4/lec/08) for example could probably help